# Nginx alias css, js only

Tags: nginx

I would like to alias all js,css to cache static, but not working. Do you know how to do this ?

```
    location ~* ^/(.*)/[^/].+.(css|js)$ {
    error_log /var/log/nginx/CssJs-log;
    alias /home/static/$1.$2;
    expires 30d;
    add_header X_Cached 1;
    error_page 403 404 502 504 = @SHtomcat;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alias with a regex location must use capture groups to specify where the ressource should be served on the filesystem.

So basically here you are trying to resolve URI `/foo/file.extension` to the physical path `/home/static/foo.extension` which seems incorrect.

I believe you instead need to resolve this to `/home/static/file.extension` so use the following :

```
location ~* ^/.*/([^/].+.(css|js))$ {
    error_log /var/log/nginx/CssJs-log;
    alias /home/static/$1;
    expires 30d;
    add_header X_Cached 1;
    error_page 403 404 502 504 = @SHtomcat;
}
```